# Group matches by line

Tags: c#, regex

I have text that is in columns like so:

```
drwxrwxrwx   1 owner    group               0 Aug 21  2017 file1.zip
-rwxrwxrwx   1 owner    group               0 Jun  2 13:03 file2.zip
-rwxrwxrwx   1 owner    group       584370643 Jun  2 13:01 file3.zip
drwxrwxrwx   1 owner    group               0 Jun  2 13:02 file4.zip
```

I have made regex to capture the column data like so:

```
/\S*[^\s]/gm
```

But it makes everything 1 group.  What I want is each group to be a separate line but I can't figure out how to use the `$` end of line operator to make this happen.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Each column is a match and each row is a group.  Current regex I posted matches columns fine but it makes only 1 group

Comment: What is your problem with 1 group?

Comment: `\S*[^\s]` is better written `\S+`

Comment: Why not splitting on spaces?

Comment: @Toto Maybe the OP views e.g. `Aug 21  2017` as being a single logical column.

Comment: I think you just need `String.Split`, see https://ideone.com/SOaxiV - if `\S+` works for you to get the right "groups". If several non-whitespace chunks may form a single "group", you may need something like Tim suggests. Then, you should add the actual requirements to the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I agree, but it seems to me simpler to split then join the 3 columns that describes the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general pattern which should match each line:

```
(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w{3}\s+\d{1,2}\s+(?:\d{4}|\d{2}:\d{2}))\s+(.*)
```

### Demo

This pattern will generate 7 capture groups, one for each column.